# Azure devops - How to use same yml for multiple git repos

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I use github for hosting my projects and have multiple projects in github. And I use Azure devops for CICD alone. I have a single project in Azure devops, where I create individual pipeline corresponding to each project in my github repo. All these github projects would need to use the same azure-pipeline.yml for build. So instead of keeping the same yml file in each project, is there a way I can keep this yml centrally. So that in future, if at all a change is required, I need not do it for all individual projects, instead, update the main yml template.

A single yml file where I have all the code is even possible for my usecase? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you may setup a repo contains all the YAML files for pipelines. Kindly also be advised that we can also keep the templates in other repositories, if we have defined the `repository resources` in the core YAML pipeline. Kindly refer to the sample Core and template YAML files below.

```
#Core YAML in Azure Repos
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: GitHub_REPO_1
    type: github
    name: GitHubAccountName/GitHubRepo1
    endpoint: GitHubServiceConnectionName
  - repository: GitHub_REPO_2
    type: github
    name: GitHubAccountName/GitHubRepo2
    endpoint: GitHubServiceConnectionName

steps:
  - checkout: none
  # - checkout: GitHub_REPO_1
  - template: GHREPO1.yml@GitHub_REPO_1
  # - checkout: GitHub_REPO_2
  - template: GHREPO2.yml@GitHub_REPO_2
```

```
#Template YAML from GitHub Repo
steps:
- script: echo "This YAML template is from GitHubRepo1"
  displayName: 'Template From GitHubRepo1'
```

By the way, we could also `checkout` the code from one or multiple repository resource(s) and trigger the pipeline by the commits from the repository resources. Please refer to the following documents for more information.

[Define YAML resources for Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource)

[Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using templates? Essentially you have would end up with a single template containing the main build steps that is reusable and individual yaml for each pipeline that can pass parameters to the template for any differences you have between them (such as different triggers or variable values). This way you can update all pipelines by making changes to the template

[Template documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

Comment: yes I have considered template - but - where do I keep this main template?

Comment: If you use a single repo, then set up a subfolder for YAML pipeline files; or if you're happy with multiple repos, a separate repo for pipeline files might be more convenient.

Comment: thanks @VinceBowdren - I have multiple projects(git repos) which will use the same yml templates. So are you suggesting to keep a repo exclusively for pipeline files? If yes, how does the other projects access this yml file which will be in a different repo during pipeline run?

Comment: The way I've set mine up is to have a repo that contains all the yaml files for pipelines. So within the repo is reusable template files and individual pipelines that call the template. The individual pipelines include triggers and parameters to customise which repo will trigger it and how it will be triggered